# Filter results from json response to only show recurring events with no end date. Python and Google Calendar API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to get a list of Calendar events which are recurring and have no end date. I've been trying to filter the json response to only return recurring events in the recurrence field, this is an example:
**'recurrence': ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20230112T235959Z;BYDAY=FR']**

I want to filter out the response to not return events which have an end date. The **UNTIL=** part above means the recurring event will end in April. I only want the events to be returned if the recurrence field is like below:
**recurrence': ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE']**

I've tried various ways to filter events with regex, substrings etc but nothing seems to work. I think a list comprehension may work here, but not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated. my code is below:

```
try:
    #call the calendar api to pull the recurring events from the resource calendar list
    page_token = None
    for el in cal_list:
        events = cal_service.events().list(calendarId=el, pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for event in events['items']:
            if 'recurrence' in event: **#return recurring events only, I've tested and this works**
                event_list.append(event)
    print(event_list)
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')

except HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

I've tried using data.find() to find UNTIL= substring but it errors out. I tried using regex and it tells me it can only be used on a string.

I've tried if **'recurrence' in event and 'UNTIL=' not in event:** and it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recurrence` is a list of strings, so:

```
if 'recurrence' in event and 'UNTIL=' not in event['recurrence'][0]:
    ...
```

or to be precise:

```
if 'recurrence' in event and all('UNTIL=' not in r for e in event['recurrence']):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Yevhen, the solution you provided on this question worked. The solution you provided on the other question I asked did not work, so thats why I did not respond to it. 

Your assistance is much appreciated. I'm new to stack overflow, so I'm not entirely sure of all the workings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If the solution isn't working, it's useful to provide feedback anyway. It might require a small fix that will be useful for you and future users.

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks again! I'll no doubt be coming back for some more assistance with this particular script, as this is one segment of a longer script. I'll give feedback on other questions from now. Cheers